# How many arrangements of the letters in STATISTICS have all of the following properties simultaneously?

Tags: combinatorics

(a)  All Ss are consecutive, AND
(b) Vowels appear in alphabetical order.

So clearly there are 10 letters in STATISTICS: 3 Ss, 3 Ts, 2 Is, 1 A, and 1 C. 
Because the Ss must be consecutive, we can treat the 3 Ss as one letter - 1 way. 
To have the vowels in alphabetical order we must have AII and we can also make this one letter - 1 way.
So now instead of having 10 spaces, we only have 6. 
Am I right so far? How do I distribute the remaining letters?

Comment: Treating the $3$ S's as a single letter is fine, but you can't make the vowels into one letter, because they may be spread along the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your treatment of the Ss is completely right.

You made a minor error in the treatment of the vowels.  Yes you can treat them as one **type** of letter, call it $\nu$, but there are still three instances of $\nu$ in the arangments.

So the problem is equivalent to the number of arrangements of $8$ symbols, two of which (SSS and C) are distinct from all other symbols, and the other six of which consist of two groups of three identical symbols ($\nu\nu\nu$ and TTT).

You then can reason:

- $8$ places to put the SSS.
- Then $7$ slots to put the C.
- Then $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ ways to choose the three slots to put the Ts.
- At which point, the slots to put the vowels are fully determined, and there is only one arrangement of the vowels allowed among those slots.

The answer, then, is

$$
8\cdot 7\cdot 20 = 1120$$